# Classification with scikit-learn KNN using multi-dimensional features (input dimension error)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn's nearest neighbor for a classification problem. My features are patches of the shape (3600, 2, 5). For example:

```
a = [[5,5,5,5,5], [5,5,5,5,5]]
b = [[5,5,5,5,5], [5,5,5,5,5]]

features = []

for i in xrange(len(a)):
    features.append([a[i], b[i]]) #I have 3600 of these in reality.

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier()

neigh.fit(train_features, target_class)

predictions = neigh.predict(test_features)
```

I get the error:

> ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Expected <= 2

This is on the line where I use `neigh.fit`. Target class is a 1 dimensional array with corresponding classes. The `train_features`, `test_features` are simply the data split into training and testing data.

Link to the same error: [check_arrays() limiting array dimensions in scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790091/check-arrays-limiting-array-dimensions-in-scikit-learn)

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use features which are themselves multi-dimensional. I'm not sure this works. Consider the increase in complexity that would occur for a distance-based metric like KNN; multi-dimensional features would require distance metrics and would get a lot more involved.

I'd first try just flattening the arrays, so that each exemplar is an n-dimensional vector, rather than an array. So if `features[0]` in your current approach is given by:

```
[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]
```

you can instead go with:

```
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

You could also consider creating new features that represent the information carried by the multi-dimensional features. You could use the mean, the max, the min, etc. Here's where your domain-specific knowledge kicks in.

Comment: I thought I may have to do this, thanks for your answer. But doesn't this create a weaker feature representation then my original un-flattened patches?

Comment: It's tough to say. When you have multi-dimensional features, the items contained within each feature are intrinsically related to each other, but once things have been flattened there's nothing special relating items that were formerly together. Ultimately this is why I think creating additional features is a good idea, because you can at least partially force such relationships to participate in the classification.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll try to create more/better features.

Answer (score 0):

It seams this it not possible.

But you can flatten features into a 1-d array than use a custom distance metric (use `metric` parameter) that before computing the distance reconstructs your features. Of course that you have to write the distance metric yourself, too. But I don`t think this is an issue.